# Why am i seeing strange error page in react

Tags: reactjs

[Strange error page (here is an image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnzFo.png)

I am trying to write my code with ReactJS and seeing such a strange picture instead of familiar to everyone

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

Try to delete the package-lock.json file and after that run

```
npm install
```

Comment: unfortunately, not works for me